# Problem in relating sentences (repeating "which")

Tags: sentence-construction, relative-clauses, relative-pronouns

I just already wrote this sentence in another website:

> I would like to run some XQuery commands using BaseX over a HTML source **which** may be full of `<script>`, `<style>` nodes **which** must be removed and also unclosed tags **which** must have a pair.

As you see, every time I need to relate some sentences I use "which" (maybe because of my native language, Persian (we use *ke* ))

I don't know is it a correct way to cascade multiple sentences or there are other natural ways?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds natural enough to me (American English).

However, if you want another option for a term, you could try "that":

> I would like to run some XQuery commands using BaseX over an HTML source that may be full of `<script>` and `<style>` nodes that must be removed, and also unclosed tags that must have a pair. (for example the dirty source of this page )

(I did some other basic editing too.)

Comment: Thank you! are you native? meanwhile I edited my sentence to replace `a pair` with `pairs` but you used the same `a pair`. is that correct?

Comment: Yes, and "a pair" sounds better. Any individual tag is only going to have a single pair.

Comment: I just read `which` is used to describe something while `that` is used to restrict something to one from many! then I tend to use `which` because I like to add something to the clause. How do you explain it?

Comment: That might be true, officially. Colloquially, nobody cares. [should be noted that this is my own opinion] If you feel that "which" is better, by all means, go ahead.